# Is it possible to pass a braced-init-list as a template argument?

Tags: c++, c++20, template-meta-programming, non-type-template-parameter, ctad

I have this class

```
template <typename ValueType, std::size_t Size>
struct ArrayPrimitive
{
  constexpr ArrayPrimitive(const ValueType (&array)[Size]) {
    std::copy(array, array + Size, data_);
  }
  ValueType data_[Size];
};
```

which is my attempt on generalizing the wrapper for passing string literals as NTTP. Then I declare this variable template, making use of CTAD

```
template <ArrayPrimitive array>
std::integral_constant<decltype(array), array> arr;
```

and afterwards use it in code as such

`for (auto i : arr<{{2,4,6}}>.value.data_) std::cout << i << std::endl;`

It compiles and properly prints all the values.

The compiler I used was the gcc13.2, I know it won't work on clang as of now due to c++20's support for class NTTP not being there yet. Also VS Code's code analyzer really doesn't like the brackets in template instantiation, which is a bit weird because it doesn't have problem with `arr<"123">`.

I want to know if it's standard compliant and won't break with future changes.

EDIT:
Looking at the answer for the bug report [GCC bug 111277](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=111277), it seems GCC has indeed implemented CWG 2450, placing it in realms of intended behaviour, however only for this one compiler.

EDIT2:
It seems it also compiles with MSVC if I write it like this https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1sThrse3x

Comment: You can change the constructor to accept `std::array` e.g. `ArrayPrimitive(const std::array<ValueType, Size> array)` and use it like `arr<std::array{2,4,6}>`, which [works on all compilers](https://godbolt.org/z/dz3vqe35o).

Comment: *"won't work on clang as of now due to c++20's support for class NTTP not being there yet"* Huh? It has had support for them for several years.

Comment: I don't think `<{...}>` is legal, GCC and MSVC reject it. If you go for `<std::array{...}>`, all three compilers accept it: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EYnxKaThh

Comment: @HolyBlackCat P0732R2 and P1907R1 are listed as partially supported, while P1814R0 is a flat no, so the full support still isn't there

Comment: @HolyBlackCat this however seem to work, but for GCC only https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8Md13vzra that's why I've wondered whether it's a compiler bug or intended behaviour not yet implemented by other compilers

Comment: Any reason not to use std::array?

Comment: @alagner from a functional standpoint, not really, it's mainly just for syntactic sugar, I'm already encoding different types on type level with constructs like val<3.5> or str<"123"> and wanted to see how close I can get to it with arrays

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code `arr<{{2,4,6}}>` is syntactically invalid. If you look at the syntax for a *[template-argument](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#nt:template-argument)*, then you will notice that this does not support expansion to a *braced-init-list*.
You have to write `arr<ArrayPrimitive{2, 4, 6}>` instead, for now.

The fact that GCC allows `arr<{{2, 4, 6}}>` is possibly related to a known [GCC bug 57905](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57905).
I have submitted a new [GCC bug 111277](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=111277).
Clang rejects it.

However, this looks to be a defect in the standard, as can be seen in [CWG 2450. *braced-init-list* as a *template-argument*](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2450.html). This issue currently has status *drafting*, which means that informal consensus was reached, but no precise wording to resolve the issue is available yet.

#### Further notes

The variable template you're suggesting is very specific, and could be generalized to work for constants of all types.
There's also no need to make a variable template with type `std::integral_constant`. `std::integral_constant` is only necessary when making a type alias template, for example.

You could write:

```cpp
template <auto value>
inline constexpr decltype(value) constant;
```

*Note: A [`std::constant` type alias similar to this](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0377r0.html) this has been suggested in a C++ proposal, but unsuccessfully.*

If you can't write `arr<{2, 4, 6}>` anyway, then you can just as well use the `constant` variable template above, like `constant<std::array{2, 4, 6}>`. This is syntactically valid because `std::array{2, 5, 6}` it is a valid *[postfix-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post.general#nt:postfix-expression)*, consisting of a *simple-type-specifier* and a *braced-init-list*.

#### Alternative solutions

If all you want is something like `for (int x : arr<{{2,4,6}}>)`, you could also write

- `for (int x : {2, 4, 6})` which relies on `std::initializer_list`
- `for (int x : arr<int>{2, 4, 6})` where `arr` is an alias template `template <typename T> using arr = T[]`
- `for (int x : std::array{2, 4, 6})`

The variable template has the advantage that it is `constexpr` and has static storage duration. However, this won't really matter for small arrays, like those with three elements.

Comment: It’s a standard [oversight](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2450.html); GCC is _supposed_ to be correct here.

Comment: @DavisHerring GCC rejects `arr<{2, 4, 6}>` though, it only accepts two levels of braces like `arr<{{2, 4, 6}}>` as in OP's code. The fact that it supports this (partially) looks mostly accidental to me. The GCC bug report also has not been closed, which further reinforces this idea.

Comment: The mentioned compiler bug refers to braced lists used during template declaration for default parameter values, here however it's in context of template instantiation, so I believe it's a different case. And yea, I've put an integral_constant here mainly as an example, though the class I'm using in my code derives from it as it fulfils all my requirements, I use it for wrapping values of structural types known during compilation  and passing them around as types for several different contexts, mainly operations involving boost::hana.

Comment: @iaks you are right; it's not exactly the same as the bug you've mentioned, but possibly related. I have submitted a new bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=111277.