# Using Arrays as Template Parameters With Default Values in C++17 and Earlier

Tags: c++, c++17, c++-templates

I need to define a C++ template that accepts several 3D coordinates as their parameters.

Why do I need this? The motivation is to create an "accessor" template for doing implicit index transformations in 3D space based on several parameters already known at compile-time, which has several useful applications. For a hypothetical example, a template may support the following feature:

1. Origin transformation: A 3D array may have been created with the origin centered around `(0, 0, 0)`. But if some formulas or algorithms are designed to work with 1-based arrays, one can use a template with the `offset` parameter set to `(-1, -1, -1)`. Similarly, if there's a need to recenter the origin at `(20, 20, 20)`, one can use a template with the `offset` parameter set to `(20, 20, 20)`.
2. Padding: Sometimes, the dimension of the 3D space must be a multiple of a certain size, in this case, one can use a template with the `padding` parameter set to `(4, 4, 4)`.
3. Blocking: Sometimes, it's more efficient to store values in the 3D space in a tiled or blocked format, so a `blocking` parameter can be used to specify the block size.

To create such a template, my first attempt is to declare it as:

```
template <
    int offset_i = 0,
    int offset_j = 0,
    int offset_k = 0,
    int padding_i = 0,
    int padding_j = 0,
    int padding_k = 0,
    int blocking_i = 0,
    int blocking_j = 0,
    int blocking_k = 0
>
class Space;
```

But as you see, when all dimensions of these coordinates are defined as separate integer variables, the parameter list would become exceedingly long - 3 coordinates need 9 parameters. This makes it hard to use, especially when the full type name of the template must be typed out with a lot of typing. For example, if a member function needs to return a 3D space, its signature would look like this:

```
Space<
    offset_i,
    offset_j,
    offset_k,
    padding_i,
    padding_j,
    padding_k,
    blocking_i,
    blocking_j,
    blocking_k
> member_function(void);
```

Thus, it's highly desirable to declare the templates in a way to use compile-time arrays, instead of compile-time integers. For convenience, it's the best if their default values can be declared directly at the location of the template declaration as values, rather than as variable names that are declared elsewhere.

In C++20, the following solution became possible:

```
template <
    std::array<int, 3> offset = std::array<int, 3>{0, 0, 0},
    std::array<int, 3> padding = std::array<int, 3>{0, 0, 0},
    std::array<int, 3> blocking = std::array<int, 3>{0, 0, 0}
>
class Space;
```

This has a much higher readability. It also simplifies the signature of member functions to:

```
Space<offset, padding, blocking> member_function(void);
```

[A proposed C++ standard change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77673096/using-arrays-as-template-parameters-with-default-values/) would simplify it even further, to:

```
template <
    std::array<int, 3> offset={0, 0, 0},
    std::array<int, 3> padding={0, 0, 0},
    std::array<int, 3> blocking={0, 0, 0}
>
class Space;
```

At this point, the original problem has already been solved in a very satisfactory manner.

However, this solution requires C++20, which may be unavailable in systems with older compiler versions.

### Question

Is there an alternative and more compatible way to achieve the same code readability goal using other techniques already available in earlier C++ versions, such as C++17? Using `std::array` is not necessary, any other methods will similar readability improvement are acceptable.

Comment: You can use built in arrays: [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1o1W97GEW)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use type parameters that have non-type parameters.

```
template <int x_, int y_, int z_> struct array3 {
  static constexpr int x = x_;
  static constexpr int y = y_;
  static constexpr int z = z_;
};

using zeros3 = array3<0,0,0>;

template <typename offset = zeros3, 
          typename padding = zeros3, 
          typename blocking = zeros3>
struct Space
{
};

Space<array3<1,2,3>> withOffsets;
```

You can constrain template parameters of `Space` to be instantiations of `array3` using SFINAE if you want.

```
static_assert(is_array3_v<offset>, "Offset must be an array3");
static_assert(is_array3_v<padding>, "Padding must be an array3");
static_assert(is_array3_v<blocking>, "Blocking must be an array3");
```

where `is_array3_v` is defined as

```
template <typename> struct is_array3 : public std::false_type {};
template <int x, int y, int z> struct is_array3<array3<x,y,z>> : public std::true_type {};
template <typename t> static constexpr bool is_array3_v = is_array3<t>::value;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an alternative and more compatible way to achieve the same code readability goal using other techniques already available in earlier C++ versions, such as C++17?

Since class type non-type template parameter are only allowed from C+20, you can use built-in array as the template parameter as shown below:

```
const int defaultArr[3]={};
//c++17 compatible
template <const int (&offsetArr)[3] = defaultArr, 
          const int (&paddingArr)[3] = defaultArr, 
          const int (&blockingArr)[3] = defaultArr>   
class Space{
    void member_function(); 
};
template <const int (&offsetArr)[3], 
          const int (&paddingArr)[3], 
          const int (&blockingArr)[3]>
void Space<offsetArr, paddingArr, blockingArr>::member_function(){
     
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1o1W97GEW)

Comment: This doesn't really work. You cannot spread code that deals with a specific instantiation of `Space` over several TUs.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a constexpr function which returns a closure (lambda are able to be used in constexpr functions since C++17). For example:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using std::array;

constexpr auto make_accessor(array<int, 3> offset = {0, 0, 0}) {
  return [=](array<int, 3> point) {
    const array<int, 3> offset_point{
      point[0] + offset[0],
      point[1] + offset[1],
      point[2] + offset[2],
    };
    return offset_point;
  };
}

void show_point(const array<int, 3>& p) {
  std::cout << "(" << p[0] << ", " << p[1] << ", " << p[2] << ")\n";
}

int main() {
  constexpr auto accessor = make_accessor({1, 2, 3});

  const array<int, 3> p1 = accessor({4, 5, 6});
  const array<int, 3> p2 = accessor({7, 8, 9});
  const array<int, 3> p3 = accessor({10, 11, 12});

  show_point(p1); show_point(p2); show_point(p3);
}
```

Behind the scenes, each call to make_accessor will effectively create an instance of an anonymous class with the parameters as constexpr members (if make_accessor is itself called in a constexpr context).