# How to deduce parameter-pack from brace-enclosed initializer list?

Tags: c++, c++20, template-specialization, parameter-pack

This is a convenience question.

I have a valid implementation of `FooImp< Aux<int...>, Aux<int...> >` in the namespace `FooDom` when both `int...` parameter packs are of same length.

My goal is being able to use the short-hand `Foo<{1,2,3},{4,5,6}>` for the verbose form `FooDom::FooImp< FooDom::Aux<1,2,3>, FooDom::Aux<4,5,6> >`. Therein, 1,2,3 and 4,5,6 are examples.

```cpp
namespace FooDom{
   template<int...> struct Aux{};
   template<typename,typename> class FooImp;
};

template<int ...u, int ...v>
using Foo<{u...},{v...}> = FooDom::FooImp< FooDom::Aux<u...>, FooDom::Aux<v...> >;
```

Question: How can I define the short-hand c++20-compliantly*?

*) I am aware or have read that brace-enclosed template initializers are not standard-compliant, yet all compilers succeed at compiling them. For the given project, the agreed standard is `-std=c++20`, so this is the version in which it should compile.

## What I tried

1. A `using` assignment, as presented in the above minimum example. The GNU G++ 12.2.0 error message with `-std=c++20` is
   `error: template parameters not deducible in partial specialization: note:'u' note:'v'`
2. Inheritance as per the following replacement:

```cpp
template<auto,auto> class Foo;

template<int ...u, int ...v>
class Foo<{u...},{v...}>: public FooDom::FooImp< FooDom::Aux<u...>, FooDom::Aux<v...> >{};
```

But `auto{}` is not c++20 compliant. So I compile with `-std=c++2b`. Then, the same error message `template parameters not deducible in partial specialization` reappears.

Comment: It's impossible. Those initializer lists are a non-deduced context. See [6. on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77074271/5740428) for more details.

Comment: To elaborate on this, `auto` cannot be deduced from `{...}` in general. It's only allowed for placeholder variables, e.g. `auto list = {...};`. Otherwise, the standard explicitly forbids this. The solution with `Aux<...>` you have is already the shortest possible workaround, and it's a fairly common solution to this problem.

Comment: @JanSchultke. Thanks! I looked deeper and found {} notation only can be used for array, which however is a value template, whereas the Aux is a type template, so then assumed from this that what I seek is impossible. I just resorted to alternating the elements of u,v.

Comment: *"I am aware or have read that brace-enclosed template initializers are not standard-compliant..."* This assumption seems wrong. The question seems to be based on a false assumption. See [CWG 2450](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2450)

Comment: *"yet all compilers succeed at compiling them, How can I define the short-hand c++20-compliantly..."* It already is standard compliant afaik. Latest versions of most compilers support braced init list as template args now. Also [Can you use a braced-init-list as a (default) template argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77673096/can-you-use-a-braced-init-list-as-a-default-template-argument)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, note that initializer lists are a non-deduced context ([What is a non-deduced context?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25245453/5740428)) and `auto` cannot be deduced from `{...}` generally. There is an exception for placeholder variables like

```cpp
auto l = {1, 2, 3; // l is of type std::initializer_list<int>
```

... however, it's not possible for template parameters or function parameters.

You can use class template argument deduction to write the following though:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <concepts>

template<std::array A, std::array B>
  requires std::same_as<typename decltype(A)::value_type, int>
        && std::same_as<typename decltype(B)::value_type, int>   
struct Foo {};

using F = Foo<{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}>;
```

`std::array` makes this somewhat fragile because there is no partial deduction, and you cannot have `std::array<int>` parameters that only deduce the size.
However, you could make such a type yourself.

Getting the individual `int`s out of the array is also possible:

```cpp
template <std::array Array>
  requires std::convertible_to<Array::value_type, int>
using expand_t = decltype([]<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    return Aux<Array[I]...>{};
}(std::make_index_sequence<Array.size()>));
```

`Foo` then becomes:

```cpp
template // ...
struct Foo : FooImp<expand_t<A>, expand_t<B>> {};
```